# c++ libxml2 xmlReadFile was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, libxml2

i use libxml2 in my Qt project i create it on linux where was everthing ok. Now I trie compile it on windows where i have this error.

```
 C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Prace-revize\revize\mainwindow.cpp:52: Error: 'xmlReadFile' was not declared in this scope
             doc = xmlReadFile(jmenoSouboru.c_str(), NULL, 0);
                                                            ^
```

omg every time it write that i must write more details

project file :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-03-25T07:37:57
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = revize
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    pridani.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    knihovna.h \
    miniz.h \
    pridani.h \
    datum.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
pridani.ui

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-std=gnu++11


win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../knihovny/libxml2/lib/ -lxml2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../knihovny/libxml2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../knihovny/libxml2/include


win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../knihovny/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a
```

everything is in this C:\knihovny\libxml2

Comment: Please show your mainwindow.cpp

Comment: ok but i run it on linux and it was ok i dont now how run libxml2 on window properly

Comment: Have you installed it? Is the INCLUDEPATH correct?

Comment: i have several version this http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libxml2.htm and cywig version and every time i have some issue.

Comment: Please show your project file, and tell use the exact location where the headers are installed to.

Comment: Why are you using `#include "knihovna.h"` instead of `#include <knihovna.h>`. Does that change fix the issue?

Comment: no, it is without change